# How to iterate different line colors when data in rows in data grid are different?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get each set of 4 point polygon to have a different color if the data from the datagrid are not the same. However, it is not drawing the line as the same color when the datagrid values are the same. It does not draw lines for the first set of 4 polygon and when I add another set of 4 polygons it switches where the new polygon does not have lines and the first set now have colored line. How do I make it sequence properly?

Code:

```cs
public partial class Form1: Form 
{
    Pen Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange, Purple, Black, Brown, HotPink, Gold;
    Graphics g2;
    Pen[] penColor;
    Graphics g;
    Point cursor;
    int countColor = 0;
    List < Point > points = new List < Point > ();

    public Form1() 
    {
        Red = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
        Blue = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
        Green = new Pen(Color.Green, 3);
        Yellow = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 3);
        Orange = new Pen(Color.Orange, 3);
        Purple = new Pen(Color.Purple, 3);
        Yellow = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 3);
        Black = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        Brown = new Pen(Color.Brown, 3);
        HotPink = new Pen(Color.HotPink, 3);
        Gold = new Pen(Color.Gold, 3);
        penColor = new Pen[] 
        {
            Red,
            Blue,
            Green,
            Yellow,
            Orange,
            Purple,
            Black,
            Brown,
            HotPink,
            Gold
        };
    }

    var row1cell1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
    var row1cell2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
    var row1cell3 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
    var row1cell4 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
    var row5cell1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i + 4].Cells[1].Value;
    var row5cell2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i + 4].Cells[2].Value;
    var row5cell3 = dataGridView1.Rows[i + 4].Cells[3].Value;
    var row5cell4 = dataGridView1.Rows[i + 4].Cells[4].Value;
    string row1c1 = row1cell1.ToString();
    string row1c2 = row1cell2.ToString();
    string row1c3 = row1cell3.ToString();
    string row1c4 = row1cell4.ToString();
    string row5c1 = row5cell1.ToString();
    string row5c2 = row5cell2.ToString();
    string row5c3 = row5cell3.ToString();
    string row5c4 = row5cell4.ToString();

    if (row1c1 == row5c1 && row1c2 == row5c2 && row1c3 == row5c3 && row1c4 == row5c4) 
    {
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2);
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx2, yy2, xx3, yy3);
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx3, yy3, xx4, yy4);
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx4, yy4, xx1, yy1);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx2, yy2, xx3, yy3);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx3, yy3, xx4, yy4);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx4, yy4, xx1, yy1);
    } 
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row5c1)) 
    {
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2);
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx2, yy2, xx3, yy3);
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx3, yy3, xx4, yy4);
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx4, yy4, xx1, yy1);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx2, yy2, xx3, yy3);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx3, yy3, xx4, yy4);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx4, yy4, xx1, yy1);
    } 
    else
    //     //(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != dataGridView1.Rows[i + 4].Cells[1].Value ||
    //     //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != dataGridView1.Rows[i + 4].Cells[2].Value ||
    //     //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != dataGridView1.Rows[i + 4].Cells[3].Value ||
    //     //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value != dataGridView1.Rows[i + 4].Cells[4].Value)
    {
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2);
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx2, yy2, xx3, yy3);
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx3, yy3, xx4, yy4);
        g.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx4, yy4, xx1, yy1);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx2, yy2, xx3, yy3);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx3, yy3, xx4, yy4);
        g2.DrawLine(penColor[countColor], xx4, yy4, xx1, yy1);
        countColor++;
    }
}
```